# reactjs pass event to next page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to pass filter value when i clik next page in my pagination. how i do this?

my get data based on filter

```
  getWHStockList(e) {
    this.toggleLoading();
    let get_wh_id = e.target.value;
    let getbyWH = '{"wh_id":"' + get_wh_id + '"}';
    this.getDatafromAPINODE(
      "/whStock/getWhStock?q=" +
      getbyWH +
      "&lmt=" +
      this.state.perPage +
      "&pg=" +
      this.state.activePage
    ).then((res) => {
      if (res.data !== undefined) {
        this.setState({
          all_data: res.data.data,
          prevPage: this.state.activePage,
          total_dataParent: res.data.totalResults
        });
        this.toggleLoading();
      } else {
        this.setState({
          all_data: [],
          total_dataParent: 0,
          prevPage: this.state.activePage,
        });
        this.toggleLoading();
      }
    });
  }
```

my handling page change

```
  handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.setState({ activePage: pageNumber }, () => {
      this.getWHStockList();
    });
  }
```

the result using above code is fine at 1st page. but when i click 2nd page `TypeError: e is undefined` because at page 2 i cant get the value of selection `e.target.value`.

So how i pass selection value to next page and so on?

**tried this**

```
// made function that store e.target.value
  getSelectionvalue = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      selected_filter: e.target.value
    });
  }

//call the getSelectionvalue in 
<Input
id="exampleSelect"
type="select"
name="select"
onChange={this.getWHStockList}
handleSelect={this.getSelectionvalue}

//and finaly call in 
  handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.setState({ activePage: pageNumber }, () => {
      this.getSelectionvalue();
      this.getWHStockList();
    });
  }
>
```

but i still `TypeError: e is undefined`

Comment: Do not pass event in this function outside this function store your `e.target.value` into any variable then pass that variable to this function.

Comment: please add to your code `handlePageChange` calls

Comment: revised my code and still get same error